# Flutter custom input dialog avoid hide by soft keyboard

Tags: flutter

I have a custom input dialog that allow to key in number, when pop out the dialog is good.
Due to the target device screen height is small 480 x 800 dpi

If click on textfield to type in number will hide bottom part of the dialog by the soft keyboard. How to avoid this?

I have try resizeToAvoidBottomInset= false under Scaffold() also same

[image]

after show up keyboard will decrease the height of dialog

[image]

Below is my custom dialog widget class to be call when using

```
class CustomInputDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Widget> columnChildren;

  CustomInputDialog({@required this.columnChildren});
  @override
  _CustomInputDialogState createState() => _CustomInputDialogState();
}

class _CustomInputDialogState extends State<CustomInputDialog> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      ),
      elevation: 10.0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      child: dialogContent(context),
    );
  }

  dialogContent(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: widget.columnChildren),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try to remove mainAxisSize.min of column

Comment: @Mohammad_Asef, have remove but still the same

Comment: Remove the `SingleChildScrollView`.

Comment: can you send columnChildren code may be the come from there